# Stored Proceedure results in Object Reference Exception

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, authentication

I have tried the following code for login check in windows programming.

My .cs file's Code is:

```
 public DataTable logincheck(String UserName, String Password)
    {
        object[] param = new object[2];
        param[0] = UserName;
        param[1] = Password;
        return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString, "proc_LoginChec", param).Tables[0];
    }
```

I am getting the object null error on the return line the error is

"**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

i dont know why this is happening.. please help me.

My App.config file is:

```
<add name="cn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.; Intial Catalog=dbRam; User id=sa; Password=xyz123#"/>
```

Comment: Check my answer. A null check on the returned DataSet should do the job.

Comment: @nunespascal i have tried your code but still throwing the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would avoid chaining your code like you have, it will be hard to debug as several object could throw an exception on that line and you wouldn't be able to pint-point which one

```
return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString, "proc_LoginChec", param).Tables[0];
```

could be re-written

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connString, "proc_LoginChec", param);
return ds.Tables[0];
```

Now, you have three lines from which exception can be thrown and you'll easily spot the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause is `ExecuteDataset` returning null when it finds no records.

You have no null check on the `DataSet` returned before accessing Tables[0].

Correct it like this:

```
public DataTable logincheck(String UserName, String Password)
{    
    DataTable dt = null;
    var ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(
                   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString,             
                   "proc_LoginChec",   
                   param);
    if(null != ds && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
      dt = ds.Tables[0];
    return dt;
}
```

Note: *you will need to do null checks later too since this function returns a null if no data was found.*

Comment: Did you check your web.config? To ensure that the connection string `cn` is set? You verify this in debug mode if this is a development machine.

Comment: Asp.net projects require a web.config file by default. App.config is used mostly by assemblies(winforms or console applications).